# "No type checking rule" error only when I supply a type checking rule

Tags: c++, boost, swig

I have a class that is predominantly used as a boost::shared_ptr. I'm trying to wrap some overloaded functions, and need to add a type-checking rule in order to make some functionality available from the Python side.

When I tell SWIG that the to use a shared pointer for my class, the SWIG wrappers build and compile fine.

```
%shared_ptr(mynamespace::MyClass)
```

Once I add a type-checking rule, however, SWIG tells me that no type checking rule is supplied! Here's my SWIG wrapping code:

```
%shared_ptr(mynamespace::MyClass)
%typemap(typecheck) boost::shared_ptr<mynamespace::MyClass> {
    // always OK, dummy for testing.
    $1 = SWIG_IsOK(1);
}
```

The error message I get is:

/scr/dbw/bld/include/header.h:509: Warning 467: Overloaded method mynamespace::get_contacts(boost::shared_ptr< mynamespace::MyClass >) not supported (no type checking rule for 'boost::shared_ptr< mynamespace::MyClass >').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why, but in this case I needed to supply a precedence for the typecheck:

```
%shared_ptr(mynamespace::MyClass)
%typemap(typecheck, precedence=SWIG_TYPECHECK_POINTER) boost::shared_ptr<mynamespace::MyClass> {
    // always OK, dummy for testing.
    $1 = SWIG_IsOK(1);
}
```

For other typechecks, I certainly didn't need to provide a precedence.

Comment: awesome. I just had this same problem today, and I found this question. I haven't thought of SO as my personal knowledge db, but, there we go.